# Preverse Activity Navigation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities, Activity A and Activity B. Activity A has a button that leads to Activity B, and when the back button pressed, it returns to Activity A as it should.

However, if I go to Activity B and minimize the app, open the app, and then press the back button, it closes the app. How can I preserve the navigation done by the user?

Comment: Use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP as your flag. Then it will work the way you desire.

Comment: @AshutoshSrivastava Originally I had set the launch mode of activity A to singleInstance, however, I changed that with the flags you mentioned and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can open using below code 

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY));
        finish();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Declare 'android:parentActivityName' in the 'AndroidManifest.xml' file.

Example:

```
<activity
android:name=".ImageActivity"
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
```